# Trying to duplicate a file without knowing its ID or name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am trying to figure out a way to check whether or not a set of folders I'm looping through has a file (google docs file) in it. If it does have a file in the folder (there's ever only one file) I would like to make a copy of it.

I'm not sure how to access that file and use the makeCopy() method since I don't know the name / ID of the file in the folder.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about following sample script? THis sample retrieves files in the `folderId`. If there is a file in the folder, the file is copied. From your question, it is found that there is only one file in the folder. So in this script, the one file is copied.

#### Sample script :

```
var folderId = "### folder ID ###";
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
var files = folder.getFiles();
var file = [];
while (files.hasNext()) {
  file.push(files.next());
}
if (file.length > 0){
  file[0].makeCopy();
}
```

#### Other sample script :

Since the file which is copied is only one, follwing sample script can be also used for your situation. This may be more simple than above.

```
var folderId = "### folder ID ###";
var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles();
files.hasNext() && files.next().makeCopy();
```

If you want to use folder name and the folder name is only one in your Drive, please use following script.

```
var folderName = "### folder name ###";
var files = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName).next().getFiles();
files.hasNext() && files.next().makeCopy();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you response, this works great if you have the Folder ID. Is it possible to tweak it to loop through folders if you only have their name? The only other method I found was getFoldersByName(); but it wouldn't take the getId() method. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ArtA If the folder name is only one in your Drive, you can use ``var files = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName).next().getFiles();`` instead of ``var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles();``.

Comment: I really can't thank you enough for your quick help! I really appreciate it :)

Comment: I have a couple followup questions if possible: 

1) If there are more than one files in the folder, and I want to copy/duplicate a specific file by file name, is there an easy way to do that?

2) Lastly, once I'm done editing the document, I would like to paste the copied document URL (which I have already stored in an object called DocURL) back into the google sheet (I was looping through) using something like: `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange([i+1],[6]).setValue(DocURL);` ... but that's not working.

Comment: @ArtA Can you submit your followup questions with the detail information as a new question?

Comment: Here is the continuation of my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45180064/duplicating-googledoc-file-by-name-in-looping-folder

Answer (score 0):

You have the ID of the folders (or at least you have their names so you can get their IDs using `files.list?q=name="foo"`

Once you have the folder IDs, you can look for any files therein using `files.list?q="folderID" in parents`